# JavaFX (Windows): How do I access the filesystem of a mobile device?

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I'm trying to make a simple backup utility which will allow me to copy files from a smartphone to a folder, either on the computer's own hard drive or an external hard drive. However, when I call the following with a mobile device connected:

```
DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
dc.showDialog(stage);
```

the resulting dialog does show my DVD drive, but not the mobile device. Why does JavaFX do this, and is there any way I can get around it?

Comment: You ever have heard about permissions?

Comment: The problem isn't as simple as it seems, and it has nothing to do with permissions. Check out [JMTP](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmtp/) for starters. It's years out of date, but it may provide some breadcrumbs for you to follow.

Comment: These days phones don't mount as file systems. They instead use a different protocol that gives the phone more control over what can be done with the files. Typically this protocol is _Media Transfer Protocol_ (MTP). I know on Windows that File Explorer is capable of interfacing with MTP devices, but "choose file/directory" dialogs cannot, at least not when opened by JavaFX. But even if they could, I'm not sure the standard I/O classes (i.e. `File` or the default `FileSystemProvider` implementations) could even handle MTP.

Comment: Interestingly, when I open a file dialog from Chrome using `<input type="file">`, it does show MTP devices.Which I think means that Chrome is able to retrieve MTP files while JavaFX cannot.